# Wrong placement in 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to print a full closed maze (where the user inputs width and height), but when I print the maze the "|" walls are not placed correct. Why is this, because the parameters are set. Also the right amount of "|" are placed but at wrong positions

```
    int vectorLength = (userRows * 2) + 1;
int vectorWidth = (userColloms * 4) + 1;


std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> maze(vectorWidth, std::vector<std::string>(vectorLength, ""));


for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorLength; i++) {
    int testj = 0;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < vectorWidth; j++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            if (j % 4 == 0) {
                maze.at(j).at(i) = "+";
            } else {
                maze.at(j).at(i) = "-";
            }
        }
        if (i % 2 != 0){
            if (j % 4 == 0) {
                maze.at(j).at(i) = "|";
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The output for input 3 3 :

+---+---+---+

||||

+---+---+---+

||||

+---+---+---+

||||

+---+---+---+

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: What's wrong with the placement? (I can see it, but I'm asking you)

Comment: There's no output in this code. Do you print spaces for the empty cells? You might consider if there's a simple formula to reduce the long `if` clauses. Maybe something like `%` which you use one line above them.

Comment: When providing output consider using a preformatted block to maintain the correct spacing. eg, `\`\`\`none<newline><output><newline>\`\`\``

Comment: Off-Topic:  `if ((j % 4) == 0) maze.at(j).at(i) = '+';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code works by replacing characters in your maze vector. Since your vector is initialized all to empty strings, there is nothing between each "|" to give space. You should either initialize your vector to be full of spaces " " or find another way to pad the space between each bar.